# Factory to return an implementation of Generic

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

I am trying to return an implementation of generic abstract class using a factory, so that the caller doesn't need to know what the concrete type returned. But failed.

## The entity classes

```cs
public class Car:IMoveable    { }
public interface IMoveable    { }
```

## The service classes

```cs
public abstract class Service<TEntity>
{
   public abstract void PerformService(TEntity t);
}

public class VehicleService : Service<IMoveable>
{
     public override void PerformService(IMoveable t) {     }
}

public class DefaultService : Service<object>
{
     public override void PerformService(object t){  }
}
```

## The factory:

```cs
public static class ServiceFactory
{
   public static Service<TEntity> CreateService<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
   {
      if (typeof(IMoveable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
      {
          // run time error here as returns null
          return  new VehicleService() as Service<TEntity>;
          //compiler error
          return (Service<TEntity>) new VehicleService();
      }
      else
      {
         return new DefaultService() as Service<TEntity>;
      }
   }
}
```

## The calling code

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var car = new Car();
   var service = ServiceFactory.CreateService(car);
}
```

The problem is the service after createService is always null.

I suspect the problem is TEntity is passed as Car, whereas the VehicleService is implemented as IMovebale. But just can't get my head around how to do it, or is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example TEntity is Car. So you try to convert object of type Service<IMoveable> to type Service<Car> ( Service<TEntity> ) but it is not possible because they are not contravariant. You can  mark type parameter with the in keyword as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark `TEntity` generic type of `Service` as [contravariant](http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/) via `in` keyword, and use base interface instead of base abstract class, then cast to generic base type will work:

```
public interface Service<in TEntity>
{
    void PerformService(TEntity t);
}
```